# AWS set policy to specific S3 bucket folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::static.MYURL.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::static.MYURL.com/images/carousel/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And currently the user under that policy can `List` all the object inside the `static.MYURL.com` bucket.

How can I restrict to only see the object under `static.MYURL.com/images/carousel/` ?

I just want that the user can list, delete, get and read object inside that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check out some helpful links provided by @amitd. Here is a sample policy that will hopefully meet your needs:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::static.MYURL.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::static.MYURL.com/images/carousel/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::static.MYURL.com"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "images/carousel/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following documents from AWS;

1. [Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

OR

2. [How can I grant a user access to a specific folder in my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-folder-user-access/)

OR

3. [How can I use IAM policies to grant user-specific access to specific folders?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/)

You can use [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)